# How to align label and input with CSS

Tags: html, css

There is the following HTML markup:

```css
    input[type="password"] {
      margin-left: 10px;
      background: #F2F2F2;
      height: 35px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-size: 14px;
      border: 0;
    }
    
    input[type="submit"] {
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      color: #fff;
      background: #000;
      font-size: 10px;
      line-height: 1.7;
      padding: 9px 29px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      transition: all 200ms ease-out;
      border: none;
      font-weight: normal;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<p>
      <label for="pwbox-59">Password: <input name="post_password" id="pwbox-59"   type="password" size="20"></label> 
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enter">
    </p>
```

How can I align inputs in one row by vertically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please see this :https://jsfiddle.net/5sy3bevb/3/

Comment: No, I meant items must be at the same row, but align by vertically

Comment: You mean aligned vertically in the same column, not row. Please edit your question to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
p {
  display:flex;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/py4x7zhk/

Comment: Simple and clean. Nice!

Comment: If this is the correct answer, I really struggle to understand what the question was. aligning items and making items the same height is not the same thing

Comment: @Brad, open snippet from question - and see how text field and submit button looks. You will notice little margin between them, and also, some bad alignment, and then compare it with fiddle....

Comment: ok fair enough, but thats not made very clear in the question, talking about vertical aligning rows etc. just a poorly worded question. glad you understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
  <div style="display:table;">
      <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">
          <label for="pwbox-59">Password: </label>
          <input name="post_password" id="pwbox-59"   type="password" size="20">
      </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enter">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is misleading, aligning items in a "row" by definition means horizontally. but then you say vertical. So i assume you mean in a column not a row.

Im assuming thats what you mean as oppose to aligning the items vertically on the row as your code is already doing that (https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/1dqLjz0o/)

You could just use the `<br>` tag when you want a line break, use margins to align

```css
label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
input[type="password"] {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 35px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 0;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  padding: 9px 29px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  border: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="pwbox-59">Password: <br>
    <input name="post_password" id="pwbox-59" type="password" size="20">
  </label> <br>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enter">
</p>
```

Comment: No, I meant items must be at the same row, but align by vertically

Comment: But they alreay are, I pastes your code in a fiddle in my answer

Comment: They are not, items are in one column, but I need that they are at the same line. Look at my source code - I need that items will be aligned good, with the same paddings/margins

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/1dqLjz0o/ this is your source code. whats wrong with it?